# Facebook iOS native application SSO not working?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I am trying to make a Facebook native iOS application, using [the iOS tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/). I did exactly as instructed, the build is successful but instead of a normal Safari login page - I only get two buttons, Cancel and Login and they don't work.

I tried the HackBook example, and it has the same exact problem when I click the login using the Facebook button.

I am using Xcode 4.2 on [Mac OS X v10.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion).

What may the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the problem. I tried to run it on my [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) and it works fine.
I logged out of my Facebook acount on the emulator and then tried to run the applications - it worked!

Strange, but it does the trick.